# Postgresql installation: command not found: createdb, psql

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I try to install postgresql via `brew`:

```
brew install postgresql@9.5
```

It installed without errors, however the console commands are not installed (e.g. `psql`, `postgresql`)

Should I do some extra steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh need just add path: `export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.5/9.5.9/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: You can also `brew install postgresql` if you don’t mind getting the latest, v10.0 release.